# Trouble deleting files or package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java/Eclipese. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjNhGaZDr0Y) on youtube. I'm trying just to delete some empty packages and some files that I don't need anymore. However, Eclipse is not letting me do so. I've also selected files that I want to delete --> go to Edit menu --> Delete. The Delete option is grayed out.

How to delete a file/package in Eclipse?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the root folder from your code base. Suppose your code is in `C:\Mycode` and you package folder start from `C:\Mycode\myproject\src\com\mypackge\bla\in\etc` just delete folder mypackage manually and refresh the project in eclipse.

I at least remove package like that once created.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse may be showing packages that really aren't there anymore.
Collapse your project in the Package Explorer.
Click F5 to refresh.
Expand your project and see if the packages are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting shouldn't be a problem most of the times. I generally use the context menu by right-clicking on the resource to be deleted and select `delete` from it. Maybe one of the resources you selected (it sounds like you mulit-selected items) can't be deleted for some reason leading to the inactivation of the menu-item. Doing it one-by-one should give you an idea which item is the culprit.

If that doesn't help you should tell a bit more, e.g. showing the hierarchy of your actual eclipse-project where you try to delete resources from and error-messages that might show up in the process of trying to delete stuff.